Unable to connect to SSH in Jetson Nano
I am trying to setup SSH in Jetson Nano (Ubuntu 18.04) with USB Tethering with my phone connected to the same wifi network as my laptop (Arch linux), but for some reason it doesn't work.
$ ssh ubuntu@192.168.1.44
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.44 port 22: No route to host

Also
$ ping 192.168.1.44        
PING 192.168.1.44 (192.168.1.44) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.16.4.4 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.16.4.4 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.16.4.4 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.1.44 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 5046ms

I tried checking firewalls ufw for if it is blocking tcp at port 22 in Jetson Nano
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To              Action             From
--              ------             ----
22              ALLOW IN           Anywhere
22 (v6)         ALLOW IN           Anywhere (v6)

I believe the problem is due to the USB Tethering I am using, but I am unable to find it out.
Thanks

Edit: Also, this is very fascinating that I can connect to my laptop's SSH from Jetson Nano by
$ ssh arch@10.240.13.153

but not the other way.
Update:
I used Termux android application to find out open ports when connected with Jetson Nano by physical cable for USB Tethering by
nmap 192.1.168.0/24

The output said that port 22/tcp is open for ssh.
But when I connected my laptop with my phone's wifi hotspot (Jetson is still using USB Tethering) used the same command in my laptop it gave me the following output for the first time.
$ nmap 192.168.1.0/24
Starting Nmap 7.95 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-10-15 05:57 IST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.142
Host is up (0.012s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed tcp ports (conn-refused)
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
53/tcp   open     domain
5060/tcp filtered sip

Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (1 host up) scanned in 8.51 seconds

Then 5060/tcp got removed on second time I ran the command.
I think I might be missing something fundamental about how USB Tethering in smart phones work.

Is route configured correctly? Show output of ip r.

On Arch:
default via 10.240.8.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 10.240.13.153 metric 600  10.240.8.0/21 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 10.240.13.153 metric 600
On Jetson Nano:
default via 192.168.1.142 dev usb1 proto dhcp metric 100  169.254.0.0/16 dev docker0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown  172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown  192.168.1.0/24 dev usb1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.246 metric 100

I think route is not set correctly on Arch, there is nothing that says how to go to 192.168.1.44. But wait, why are Arch and Jetson Nano in different subnets?

May be because Jetson Nano is using USB tethering from my phone, but my phone is connected to the same wifi network as Arch.

I would try adding an 192.168.1.x address on Arch and creating a route for it, then run ip r get 192.168.1.44 to make sure that the correct route is used.

Although I could not figure out why things were not working, I got a workaround.
As I can run ssh server on my phones Termux and also use Termux to connect to Jetson Nano's ssh, I ran ssh inside ssh.
Assuming SSH server is setup in Jetson Nano, it is connected to the Android phone for USB tethering and you can connect to your phone's and the laptop and phone is in the same wifi network.
Step 1: Start ssh server in Termux by running sshd. Make sure to install ssh server in Termux.
Step 2: You might need to change password for ssh by running passwd in Termux.
Step 3: Get your phone ip address from Termux.
$ pkg update
$ pkg install ifconfig

And
$ ifconfig|grep -A 1 "wlan0" 
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.7.51.67  netmask 255.255.192.0  broadcast 10.7.63.255

Here 10.7.51.67 is the ip address for phone. Note that this is for wifi only.
Step 4: Connect to your phone's ssh from your laptop:
Default port for ssh in Termux is 8022. Also you might need to check <host-name> by running hostname in Termux.
$ ssh -p 8022 <host-name>@<ip-address>

Step 5: And finally, connect to your Jetson Nano from the ssh shell
$ ssh <hostname-for-jetson>@<jetson-ipaddress>

